# Error 500: Heroku logs , is it the database causing the problem?

Tags: python, heroku

I have the following problem after trying to push my website in Heroku.
the Heroku logs show:

```
 State changed from starting to up
2023-01-17T21:01:22.003674+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-01-17 21:01:22 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2023-01-17T21:01:22.004317+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-01-17 21:01:22 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:37013 (4)
2023-01-17T21:01:22.004413+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-01-17 21:01:22 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2023-01-17T21:01:22.015171+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-01-17 21:01:22 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2023-01-17T21:01:22.097661+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-01-17 21:01:22 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2023-01-17T21:01:26.689186+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=cv-website.herokuapp.com request_id=e9f7f7dd-8f4f-4e8c-9aaa-621fc8c59950 fwd="78.141.167.72" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3815ms status=500 bytes=436 protocol=https
2023-01-17T21:01:26.688612+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.25.53 - - [17/Jan/2023:22:01:26 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-01-17T21:01:41.809594+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=cv-website.herokuapp.com request_id=5303ead2-743f-41b3-b342-3a55280f1280 fwd="78.141.167.72" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=949ms status=500 bytes=436 protocol=https
2023-01-17T21:01:41.809168+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.25.53 - - [17/Jan/2023:22:01:41 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-01-17T21:00:50.276696+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 8aa4e515 by user henryphilippe.dumont@gmail.com
2023-01-17T21:00:50.276696+00:00 app[api]: Release v21 created by user henryphilippe.dumont@gmail.com
2023-01-17T21:01:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

My setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/assets/img/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/assets')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') # New version of Django of code could be : BASE_DIR / 'static'

]
```

my_website_parameters

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('CV_Website.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # to check doc about the urlpatterns +=static(settings.MEDIA_URL , document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

[![Website structure][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdcrY.png

Is there a way that it is caused by the root static file?
It is caused by the URLs.py file?  it is something else from the website that I missed doing?

Comment: If you got a 500 error what does django say happened? in debug mode django should show the stacktrace and what error was thrown

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide , thank you  i haven't thought about it . I manage because of you to debug. :)